# Using more than one queries on perl DBI

Tags: sql, perl

I'm sure there is a better way to do this on the same line, but I'm unable to figure out how, since I'm a beginner in Perl. Basically what I need to do is select, delete and count the results.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT env,server, mwp.is_reference where env='$ARGV[1]';");
$sth->execute();

$sth2 = $dbh->prepare("delete from mwp.is_info_package where env='$ARGV[1]'");
$sth2->execute();

$sth3 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(1) from mwp.is_reference where env='$ARGV[1]'");
$sth3->execute()
```

The objective is how do i use the 3 queries at the same line, instead having 3 executes.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.i.e. Add above statement there rather than putting it in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the following query statement:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select env,iserver, ( select count(1)  from is_reference where env='$ARGV[1]' ) as total from is_reference where env='$ARGV[1]'");
```

not the most elegant way, but solved my problem with the less lines. Regarding the delete query, i moved to another condition to check if the table have data or not.

THanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could start out using placeholders ( `'?'` ).

```
my @qlist
    = ( 'SELECT env,server FROM mwp.is_reference where env=?'
      , 'DELETE mwp.is_info_package WHERE env=?'
      , 'SELECT count(1) FROM mwp.is_reference where env=?'
      );
```

And then you can iterate through them like this:

```
my $env = $ARGV[1];

foreach my $query ( @qlist ) { 
    $dbh->prepare( $query )->execute( $env );
    Carp::croak( $dbh->errstr ) if $dbh->err;
}
```

But of course, you really want to *select* the two outputs, don't you?

```
use Carp qw<croak>;

my $select_query = 'SELECT env,server FROM mwp.is_reference where env=?';
my $delete_query = 'DELETE mwp.is_info_package WHERE env=?';
my $count_query  = 'SELECT count(1) FROM mwp.is_reference where env=?';
my %empty_atts;

my $rows 
    = $dbh->selectall_arrayref( $select_query, \%empty_atts, $env )
    ;
croak( $dbh->errstr ) if $dbh->err;
$dbh->prepare( $delete_query )->execute( $env );
croak( $dbh->errstr ) if $dbh->err;
my ( $count ) 
    = $dbh->selectrow_array( $count_query, \%empty_atts, $env )
    ;
croak( $dbh->errstr ) if $dbh->err;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a stored procedure that performs those functions and returns the results of the select as well as a count, then you only need to do:

```
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare("EXEC procedure_name ?");
 $sth->execute( $ARGV[1] );
```

As an aside, the way you're using prepare and execute is undesirable. You use prepare to avoid having to have Perl variables directly in the query; your Perl variables should be passed to `execute()` as values, not part of the string given to `prepare()`. There are a number of good reasons to do this, including protection against SQL Injection attacks.

I also noticed oddness in your last SQL query. I think you probably want

```
SELECT count(env) FROM mwp.is_reference where env=?
```

Otherwise it will always return "1" as the count...  Likewise, unless there are database triggers doing something interesting, you could combine the first and last query into one this way (I'll leave `count(1)` for this in case that's really what you want):

```
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT env,server FROM mwp.is_reference where env=?');
 $sth = $sth->execute( $ARGV[1] );
 my $result_set = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
 my $count = scalar @{ $result_set };
```

The `$result_set` will be a reference to an ARRAY of ARRAYRefs containing the results; `$count` will contain the number of rows in that result set.

Comment: `count(env)` is probably the wrong thing here, it will only count rows where `env` is not null, but the where clause will only allow rows with a not null `env` effectively counting all rows returned, `count(1)` will count all rows returned always. So both will, in this case, return the same results. But `count(column)` has slight portability issues (some databases count rows where `column` is null) and will perform worse on some databases.